# How to execute many commands in 1 batch file using 1 psql?

Tags: batch-file, psql

I'm trying to run a batch file to execute many commands in 1 psql shell

I'm using Postgres version 11.4

This is my code:

```
@ECHO OFF
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin\psql.exe" "dbname=databasename 
host=hostname user=username password=@bcd1234 port=5432 sslmode=require"
DELETE from my_table1;
DELETE from my_table2;
DELETE from my_table3;
PAUSE
```

I expect the script delete all data from 3 tables, but it only run the first command line to login Postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute multiple commands by executing them from a file.

1. **Create a file** and write all your commands in it.
2. Use the `-f` option to **pass the file** as the source of commands.

Please refer: (`-f` option) https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/app-psql.html

Comment: Yeah. It works for me. Thank you Anurag. My code is  @echo off
SET PGPASSWORD=@bcd1234
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin\psql.exe" -h hostname -U username -d databasename -p 5432 -a -f "D:\testscript.sql
pause